# Adding sqlcmd context reference to a VS2010 Database projects' SQL files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to add a 'right-click' context menu for .sql files within a VS 2010 database project?

I'd like to add this to rapidly deploy files to a test environment while being able to parse variables within the .sql files.